# Postgres `statement_timeout` with indexing

Tags: postgresql, indexing, timeout

I would like to set the `statement_timeout` for the DB but I know indexing takes a lot of time.
Is the `statement_timeout` also relevant for indexing?

Comment: It is relevant for any statement. You can set the default and then override it in a particular transaction/connection though.